# Number of cyclic words of length r with n letters

Tags: co.combinatorics

The answers to these questions are presumably well known (and easy?).

Question 1: Given an alphabet of n letters (1,2,...n), how many distinct words of length r exists, considered up to cyclic permutation?

Question 2: How many such cyclic words exist if we do not allow the 2-letter subword "12"?.

Comment: Q1 is done easily by means of Mobius inversion, you can find answers everywhere really as one of the first examples of Mobius inversion. For Q2, I do not know any reference, but you can use inclusion-exclusion principle and look at number of words with at least $k$ occurrences of 12?

Comment: Vladimir's right about question 1, but it might be good to give a definite reference. See Free Lie Algebras by Christophe Reutenauer, Corollary 7.3.

Answer (score 1):

Q2: Essentially you want to know what is the number of periodic sequences of (minimal) period $r$ for the subshift of finite type given by the $n\times n$ matrix $M_n$ such that $M_{12}=0$ and $M_{ij}=1$ for all $(i,j)\neq (1,2)$.

The answer is $\text{trace}(M_n^r)$ - see [Katok & Hasselblatt, Modern Theory of Dynamical Systems, Corollary 1.9.5]. I am pretty sure this can be computed explicitly in this case.

Comment: Why "minimal"? Or you mean that then we sum up things over all divisors?